# Is there correspondence between vector spaces and independent theories?

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms, formal-systems

I'm not a mathematician, but I have this idea.

A **vector space** is defined by a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), that is a set of linearly independent vectors.
On the other hand, an **independent theory** is defined by a set of independent axioms. A set of axioms is said to be [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)) if neither of them can be proved from the others.

Correspondence can be recognized in the following parallel sentences:

1. A vector space over a field is defined by a set of linearly independent basis vectors.
2. New vectors can be expressed as linear combinations of basis vectors.
3. A vectorial basis spans a vector space.

*vs.*

1. An independent theory over a formal language is defined by a set of logically independent axioms.
2. New statements (theorems) can be derived as combinations of axioms.
3. An axiomatic system "spans" a [deductive theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)#Deductive_theories).

If the correspondence holds, the following questions make sense:

- Is it possible to assign coordinates to the theorems of an independent theory?
- A vector space may have multiple bases. Is it possible to translate this statement into the language of axiomatic systems?

*Disclaimer*: I tried to be as exact as I could be. Feel free to correct me if I accidentally misused some concepts.